# no space in disk : sudo apt-get clean not working

Tags: 14.04

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  292G  174G  103G  63% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         902M  4.0K  902M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        183M  1.3M  182M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         913M  156K  913M   1% /run/shm
none                         100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M  185M   39M  83% /boot
```

I use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output o `df -i`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably interested in installing updates (new kernel versions?) and it's not allowing you, right?

If so, I suggest you download [Ubuntu-Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

After installing, open it and go to the tab named *Janitor*. Once there, you can easily clean space in order to be able to install new updates.